# Can't retrieve data from SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

I have a program that inserts some values from text boxes into database. The problem is that the values are stored successfully into db but I can't get them into my Data Grid View...here's the code:

```
    public void LoadMuzee(DataGridView table)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" + "Initial Catalog=lista_muzee;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT muzee.*, gen.gen_nume " +
                                        "FROM muzee INNER JOIN gen " +
                                        "ON muzee.muz_gen_id = gen.gen_id", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        sa.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        sa.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Dispose();
        table.DataSource = dt;
        table.Columns["muz_id"].Visible = false;
        table.Columns["muz_gen_id"].Visible = false;
    }
    public frmMuzee()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadMuzee(dgvMuzee);
    }
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get any errors, exceptions? What do you get if you execute the same query with same parameters outside of your application?

Comment: Try opening the connection before declaring the data adapter?

Comment: @Mihai-DanielVirna, that's complete absurd ....

Comment: Plus, I would populate the grid after the form loaded and not in constructor?

Comment: Have you tried to check data stored in `dt` before `conn.Close();` and after `sa.Dispose();`?

Comment: @erikscandola yes, and there is no data stored...

Comment: This is weird because I have a similar project and it works without problems...

Comment: Ok, and have you tried the select query in sqlserver?

Comment: Yes...it returns no values. It seems that here is the problem

Answer (score 0):

your not performing databind on your gridview which causes data not get binded into gridview

table.databind()